# The problem is that Czech babel makes "-" an active character (whatever that means)

Tags: babel, cline

I write reports in Czech, so naturally, I use the Czech babel package. The problem is that Czech babel makes "-" an active character. I've found that problems arise when I use these libraries

- [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)
- [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)

I am using the solutions provided in the StackExchange answer:

```
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}
\preto\siunitx{\shorthandoff{-}}
```

which makes the "**-**" character non-active in the used packages. I use a lot of libraries and it's exhausting to find which library is affected.

My question is, whether there is a way to tell to *babel library* -> do not switch the meaning of the "-" character  in a foreign environment. I use utf fonts and for translation **lualatex**. Perhaps it is possible to use Lua language for this task. But I don't really understand any of it. It would also help me explain what is going on. I tried to figure it out, but my idea is still vague.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[main=czech]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}
\preto\siunitx{\shorthandoff{-}}

\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
  Number with siunitx \num{1e-9}

 \begin{equation*}
   \polylongdiv[style=C,div=:]{x^4+3x^3-3x^2+3x}{x^2+1}
 \end{equation*}

 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
   A & B & C \\
  \cmidrule{2-3}
  A & B & C \\
  \cline{1-2}
  A & B & C \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but `\preto\siunitx{...}` does nothing at all.

Comment: you can just use `\shorthandoff{-}` at the top level in the document of you don't want that special meaning of -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not use the `-` shorthand just turn it off, there is no need to patch every command separately.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[main=czech]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}



\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{-}

  Number with siunitx \num{1e-9}
 \begin{equation*}
   \polylongdiv[style=C,div=:]{x^4+3x^3-3x^2+3x}{x^2+1}
 \end{equation*}

 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
   A & B & C \\
  \cmidrule{2-3}
  A & B & C \\
  \cline{1-2}
  A & B & C \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In modern (unicode) times probably `shorthand=off`  when loading babel should be the preferred option...

Comment: @Rmano possibly (not that I use any shorthands for English anyway:-) But even in 2021 using a UK keyboard it is still a lot easier to type `\'e`  than  `é` (I know that isn't a babel shorthand but still...)

Comment: @Rmano making `-` a shorthand at all is unfortunate.

Comment: I think that one of the reason I am so reticent to change from Linux is the Compose key. `Compose` (which is CapsLock in my keyboard - never used Caps lock anyway)  `'` `e` do the trick (well, in my laptop I have a US + AltGr dead key layout that I think it's the better layout ever)

Comment: @Rmano on this keyboard actually altgr+e makes é but how do you make a grave or a polish slashed l or ...  it's same as math, I can type ∫ but typing \int is a whole lot easier

Comment: @DavidCarlisle compose \` e, compose L /... :)